# Start Rails server with an absolute path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, absolute-path

I'm trying to make a script to run my Rails dev server, but the absolute path doesn't want to work.

This is what I've got;

`/home/me/dev/app/script/rails server >> /var/log/rails.output.log`

It just throws an error saying,

> "configuration /home/me/config.ru not found"

It appears that Rails is using the current working directory to get it's paths, rather than the script location.

Is there a way to force the app path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`cd /home/me/dev/app && script/rails server >> /var/log/rails.output.log`

Comment: Actually worked perfectly. I had thought of that, but didn't try it because for some reason I expected the cd to persist and screw other things up, but apparently it only changed directories for the rest of the command sequence.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative:

> ruby /home/me/dev/app/script/rails s -c /home/me/dev/app/config.ru -P /home/me/dev/app/tmp/pids/server.pid >> /var/log/rails.output.log

Comment: Tried this and it worked, but the cd one was simpler. For some reason I was expecting the cd to persist, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Stephen Belanger, I agree that @Aaron Hinni (+1 to him) solution is better, so it was just as alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe `rails server` had an option you could pass to it, to change the path, but it doesn't [look like](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb) that's the case.

You are able to pass a `-c` flag and specify your own configuration, maybe that has something to do with it?